# Object property set to null

Tags: ios, object, null

Can someone please see where I am going wrong with this?

I have a object called Object with a single NSString property.

I then have a MainViewController with a button on it. The button is created programatically and added at runtime.

When yo click this button, it is supposed to set the value of the Object proper to a String, and pass this to the next ViewController.

I manage to set the value of the Object property, but when I call that value to pass it, it is set to null. I have tried many different solutions but nothing seems to work. Can anyone see where my problem lies? I have added all the relevant code below

Object.h

```
@interface Object : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;
```

Object.m

```
#import "Object.h"
@implementation Object
@synthesize content;
```

Then in MianViewController I create the button and set value of Object property
MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SecondaryViewController.h"
#import "Object.h"
.
.
@synthesize myButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.tag = 1;
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 140, 280.f, 40.f);
    UIImage *airButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereByAirButton.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:airButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) myButtonClicked
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Getting Here...");

    Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
    object.content = @"This is the content of the Object";

    NSLog(@"Content of Object Set To: %@", object.content);

    SecondaryViewController *vc;
    vc.object = object;

    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    NSLog(@"Object.content: %@", object.content);
    NSLog(@"ViewController.object.content: %@", vc.object.content);

    NSLog(@"Just Did Stuff...");
}
```

And the SecondaryViewController where the label should be set to that of the Object String
SecondaryViewController.h

```
#import "Object.h"

@interface SecondaryViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contentLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Object *object;
```

SecondaryViewController.m

```
@synthesize object;
@synthesize contentLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Content of Object: %@", object.content);

    self.contentLabel.text = object.content;
}
```

And finally a screen grab of my NSLog when the app is running [HERE](http://imm.io/1k1nD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SecondaryViewController *vc;
```

Should be

```
SecondaryViewController *vc = (SecondaryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

Comment: OK so I don't know what I did but I tried this earlier and it did not work for me. Changed it as per answer and now working perfectly. Thanks a million